# get product seo url from id

Tags: product, url, url-rewrite, seo

i want to get product seo url from id

below is code i used to get url from id

```
$my_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id); 
$my_product_url = $my_product->getProductUrl();
```

but above code gives url like :
catalog/product/view/id/226/s/slot-ring/category/58/

how to get seo url here like :
/rings-10/start-with-setting.html

Comment: please reindex the url rewrite

Comment: its already reindex , i am trying to get url from id

Comment: Check this, maybe that is what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557598/magento-getting-a-products-rewritten-url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with following code:

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$path = Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->getRequestPathByIdPath('product/456', $store);

$url = $store->getBaseUrl($store::URL_TYPE_WEB) . $path;
```

Just replace `456` with your product id.

Comment: for some product in multiple catgeory it does not give current category path in url pls help