# Get SEO friendly product url in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, url, product-urls

I have a template file that 'gets' the product url so that I can produce a link to the product. However, the url called is not the SEO friendly version. Can anyone suggest an edit to the code below so that I can get the preferred SEO friendly URL instead?

**Current URL**

example.com/catalog/product/view/id/419/category/252

**Preferred SEO Friendly URL**

examples.com/my-product.html

**PHTML - My Current Code**

```
<?php $product = $categoryProducts->getFirstItem();?>
 <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()?>">Product Link</a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I think your question is answered here: [Magento Stack Exchange: get product seo url from id](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52450/get-product-seo-url-from-id)

Answer (score 2):

As per as your code,you **have tried to get product($product) 's** *Seo Url  from a product collection* `($categoryProducts)`.

In order  to **get seo url you need** to add `addUrlRewrite()` function to that collection `($categoryProducts)`.

**So changes**

```
<?php $product = $categoryProducts->getFirstItem();?>
```

**to**

```
<?php 
$categoryProducts->addUrlRewrite();
$product = $categoryProducts->getFirstItem();?>
```

Also,please check **Magento indexing Management is working or not at syst**em